# Clipping satellite imagery taken at angle where projection data cannot be removed using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, clip, error

I am using QGIS to clip satellite imagery that has been taken at an angle, and where projection data cannot be removed. When I attempt to clip the imagery, I get this error:

> GDAL command output: ERROR 1: the -projwin option was used, but the
> geotransform is rotated. This configuration is not supported. Input
> file size is 35180, 19348 Process returned error code 1

In technical terms, what is the cause of this error, and what is the way to solve it?

Comment: I don't really know without testing, but I guess the geotransform has non-zero rotations, and projwin is complaining about that. You could use the geotransform to calculate the pixel locations "by hand" and then use the `srcwin` option?